# Bootstrap 4 - Full Height Drawer

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on an app that uses Bootstrap 4. In addition, I'm using the [material design framework](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/). I need this app to take up the entire screen and to use the drawers that are part of the framework. I can successfully get the app to take up the entire screen by using a flexbox. However, I can't seem to get the drawer to take up all of the available height. You can see the issue in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/98970/). The code in that Fiddle looks like this:

```
<div id="app" class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
    <div class="h-100 flex-grow">
      <div class="bmd-layout-container bmd-drawer-f-l bmd-drawer-overlay">
        <div id="appDrawer" class="bmd-layout-drawer bg-faded">
          <div class="container">
            <header>Hello</header>
            <p>
              This is a longer block of information text.
              Regardless of how long this block of text is,
              the drawer should extend all the to the footer.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <main class="bmd-layout-content">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>
            Hello
            </h1>

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" data-toggle="drawer" data-target="#appDrawer">Show Info</button>

          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>


    <footer>
      <p>Thank you for visiting!</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

How do I make the drawer take up the entire height between the `nav` and `footer` areas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to make the element that wraps `.bmd-layout-container` a flex parent with flex-direction: column, then set the generated `.bmd-layout-canvas` class to `flex-grow: 1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.bmd-layout-canvas {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
    <div class="h-100 flex-grow d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="bmd-layout-container bmd-drawer-f-l bmd-drawer-overlay">
        <div id="appDrawer" class="bmd-layout-drawer bg-faded">
          <div class="container">
            <header>Hello</header>
            <p>
              This is a longer block of information text.
              Regardless of how long this block of text is,
              the drawer should extend all the to the footer.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <main class="bmd-layout-content">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>
            Hello
            </h1>
            
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" data-toggle="drawer" data-target="#appDrawer">Show Info</button>

          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
    

    <footer>
      <p>Thank you for visiting!</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/n9c4Lbqa/

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the height in `vh` units. 1vh is equal to 1% of the window height (100vh = 100%). If you combine it with calc, you can set it to fill the window height minus the other elements.

```
.element {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Replace the 50px with whatever number is enough to clear the height / footer in your design.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the prettiest way to do this, but works.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });
```

```css
#app {
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fill {
  height: 100%;
}

.test-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" />

<div id="app" class="d-flex flex-column fill">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="flex-grow p-r test-wrap">
    <div class="h-100 flex-grow test">
      <div class="bmd-layout-container bmd-drawer-f-l bmd-drawer-overlay">
        <div id="appDrawer" class="bmd-layout-drawer bg-faded">
          <div class="container">
            <header>Hello</header>
            <p>
              This is a longer block of information text.
              Regardless of how long this block of text is,
              the drawer should extend all the to the footer.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <main class="bmd-layout-content">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>
            Hello
            </h1>

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" data-toggle="drawer" data-target="#appDrawer">Show Info</button>

          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer>
    <p>Thank you for visiting!</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**Here the flex way**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });
```

```css
#app {
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" />

<div id="app" class="d-flex flex-column">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="flex-grow d-flex test-wrap">
    <div class="flex-grow test"><!-- removed h-100 -->
      <div class="bmd-layout-container bmd-drawer-f-l bmd-drawer-overlay">
        <div id="appDrawer" class="bmd-layout-drawer bg-faded">
          <div class="container">
            <header>Hello</header>
            <p>
              This is a longer block of information text.
              Regardless of how long this block of text is,
              the drawer should extend all the to the footer.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <main class="bmd-layout-content">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>
            Hello
            </h1>

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" data-toggle="drawer" data-target="#appDrawer">Show Info</button>

          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer>
    <p>Thank you for visiting!</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/105279/

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;

}
#app {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.flex-grow {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.push {
  height: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app" class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My App</a>
  </nav>

  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow push">
    <div class="h-100 flex-grow">
      <div class="bmd-layout-container bmd-drawer-f-l bmd-drawer-overlay">
        <div id="appDrawer" class="bmd-layout-drawer bg-faded">
          <div class="container">
            <header>Hello</header>
            <p>
              This is a longer block of information text.
              Regardless of how long this block of text is,
              the drawer should extend all the to the footer.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <main class="bmd-layout-content">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>
            Hello
            </h1>

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" data-toggle="drawer" data-target="#appDrawer">Show Info</button>

          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>


    <footer class="flex-column h-100">
      <p>Thank you for visiting!</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```